# How do I make a gradient overlay transparent?

Tags: css, transparency

The site I'm working on has three layers (from the bottom): a tiled background image, a simple top-to-bottom gradient, and the actual content window on top. I am trying to change the opacity of the gradient itself so that it will give the background a faded appearance as well as some color.

However, whenever I try to add opacity to the gradient div (opacity: 0.4;), for some reason it yanks the tiled-image background layer to the front (covering everything) and makes the "background" only slightly transparent.

How do I get the gradient to become transparent without this happening?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer without knowing what browser you're experiencing the problems in, the code you talk about isn't cross browser compliant.

Best way to achieve a cross browser gradient, outside of [using html 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681813/css3-transparent-background-image-and-gradient), is to use a [transparent 24-bit png](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/web_standards_creativity_png/).